# OpenVAS won't generate SCAP Database

Tags: server, kali-linux, vulnerability-scanners, vulnerability-assessment, openvas

To deploy OpenVAS to Virtual machines I've been using Ansible for a while and it worked pretty well. Now today I wanted to deploy it to another machine but the `openvas-check-setup` script keeps telling me that the setup isn't yet finished because the SCAP database is missing which it in fact is.

> ERROR: No OpenVAS SCAP database found. (Tried:
>   /var/lib/openvas/scap-data/scap.db) FIX: Run a SCAP synchronization
>   script like greenbone-scapdata-sync.

The suggested solution doesn't solve the problem. The directory `/var/lib/openvas/scap-data` does exist and it is by no means empty. The only file that seems to be missing is the `scap.db`.

To validate the process I moved all the files from `/var/lib/openvas/scap-data` to a temporary drive and ran `greenbone-scapdata-sync` again. All the files that had been there before where downloaded again but the SCAP Database is still missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be the case that an `apt-get dist-upgrade` caused the trouble. After setting up another VM leaving this step out the installation finished sucessfully.

// Eventhough I got it running I'm now using Ubuntu Server and the packets provided by [Mohammad Razavi](https://launchpad.net/~mrazavi/+archive/ubuntu/openvas) when it comes to virtualized instances of OpenVAS. I had severe problems handling the scans. The scan processes started but hung themselfes after 1% - 9% and did never finish. Didn't have to deal with problems like this in presvious versions of kali.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the `greenbone-scapdata-sync --help` for some other options that may work; specifically these:

```
greenbone-scapdata-sync --refresh
greenbone-scapdata-sync --refresh-private
```

As far as I can tell, they are specifically designed to rebuild `scap.db` when the other files in `/var/lib/openvas/scap-data` are present. Worked for me, anyway.